# Txfonts causes misalignment of symbols in an equation block

Tags: amsmath, matrices, alignment, txfonts

I have encountered issue with **symbols alignment (`&`) within the `matrix`** in an `equation` block - are on the each other in one row. Issue is most likely associated with `txfonts` package. Matrix's symbols are well-aligned without the package, however I would like to keep it due to roman fonts it provides.

Example using `amsmath` with `txfonts`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, openany, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\begin{document}
\chapter{...}
Minimalizacja tranzystorów i konieczność brania efektów kwantowych pod uwagę.
\section{...}
\begin{equation}
    X = \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        c & d & d \\
        e & f & g \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

How can use `txfonts` but with a proper alignment for example for `amsmath` matrices?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I cannot recreate that issue, using the simplest of examples: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,txfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
X = 
    \begin{bmatrix} 
    a & b & c \\
    c & d & d\\
    e & f & g \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}`.  Obviously, you need to provide more information.

Comment: please always post a complete document that demonstrates the problem. Also if you get an error, show the error not the output image.

Comment: I was able to recreate this issue in Overleaf with minimal settings:

`
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, openany, a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}

\chapter{...}
Minimalizacja tranzystorów i konieczność brania efektów kwantowych pod uwagę. 
\section{...}

\begin{equation}
X = 
    \begin{bmatrix} 
    a & b & c \\
    c & d & d\\
    e & f & g \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
`

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code for the example.  Anyone asking a question is always permitted to edit it, regardless of how active they have been on the site.

Comment: Don't use `txfonts`. It's buggy and causes problems. Do `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes this weird behavior with `txfonts`, but I'd suggest using the packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` instead of `txfonts`.

Using your example, the output is basically the same, except for the matrix which looks alright with `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` but not with `txfonts`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, openany, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
%\usepackage{txfonts}
\begin{document}
\chapter{...}
Minimalizacja tranzystorów i konieczność brania efektów kwantowych pod uwagę.
\section{...}
\begin{equation}
    X = \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        c & d & d \\
        e & f & g \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]